# На сервере закончилось свободное место, новые файлы не создаются, вывод df -h показывает что свободное место есть

Tags: linux, devops

У меня есть такой вопрос для прохождения теста на стажировку:

> На сервере закончилось свободное место, новые файлы не создаются,
> вывод df -h показывает что свободное место есть. Опишите причины по
> которым такое могло произойти?

Я ответил так

> По-умолчанию файловая система ext4 резервирует под служебные нужды 5%
> свободного места на разделе. На больших дисках это бывает много.
> Изменить такое поведение можно, сказав в терминал подмонтированному
> разделу: tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1 где 1 - количество резервируемого
> места в процентах (0% тоже можно), а /dev/sda1 - раздел, к которому
> это применить Эффект немедленный и без перезагрузок. Также после этого
> можно слегка дефрагментировать этот смонтированный раздел: e4defrag
> /dev/sda1

Они ответили так:

> есть еще 2 случая когда такое возможно, они не раскрыты и снимать
> резерв с рута не имеет смысла, так как в условиях задачи указано что
> "место есть"

Как скажете какие еще два случае?

Comment: inode кончились

Comment: я не очень хорошо понимаю, в каком контексте задаётся вопрос, но как Вам такой сценарий: пусть программе примонтирован раздел диска, к примеру, в /MyData/ Программа в этот раздел пишет, и его исчерпала. При этом вне этого раздела место на диске есть.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://serverfault.com/a/384554) ещё пишут, что максимальный размер метаданных у каталога ограничен (лично не проверял)

Comment: в порядке теорий заговоров: кто-то мог подменить `df` или модуль ФС, дабы он возвращал ошибку, что нет места… в порядке человеческой глупости: ты смотришь `df` не на том разделе/хосте… из более разумных вариантов: исчерпаны иноды, на разделе включены и исчерпаны квоты…

Comment: получается два случая - исчерпаны иноды и исчерпаны квоты получается?

Comment: каким боком тут тэг `sql`?

Comment: @Anatoly нечаянно добавил

Comment: Очень интересные эффекты получаются, когда _/tmp_ забит под завязку. Но об этом авторы вопроса видимо не спрашивают.